# The process of loading OBJ files into Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying two upload one OBJ and its associated MTL files into a WebGL scene using the lovely Three.js.

I have just came up with an issue which I can't find a justification for that. I have put some global variables in my code to monitor what is going on when loading the OBJ and MTL files. Although it is just one set of files, the "obj" variable is from "Group" type and it does have two "children". It is not itself instance of mesh but its children are, as console.log() says. However, when I am checking inside children, the first one -- which is measured by geo[0] -- contains just vertices and the "faces" array is empty. However, the second child -- measured by geo[1] -- has all the vertices and faces. It is even enough to just use geo[1] to get the same scene when you use obj.

My concern is the logic behind this. Why for a set of OBJ and MTL files we have an object with two children in which the first children has just vertices and the second one has vertices again and also faces.

It is important for me because I want to work on the vertices and faces to get a voxelized volume and this needs direct manipulations on the scene objects.

```
scapula = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
scapula.load('obj/scapulaTWO.obj', 'obj/scapulaTWO.mtl', function (object) {
    // var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xFFFF66
    });
    obj = object; //group

    object.traverse(function (child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            console.log(child instanceof THREE.Mesh)

            geo[i] = child; //mesh
            // apply custom material
            child.material = material;

            // enable casting shadows
            child.castShadow = true;
            child.receiveShadow = true;

            i = i + 1;
        }
    });

    scene.add(geo[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you will find in your object after it has been parsed by the loader is produced by your model.

You can open your *.obj with a text editor and see the groups etc. for yourself. Its not like three.js rips out the vertices and puts them in a seperate group.